# I need rows colored alternatively but in doubles

Tags: rowcolor

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ paperwidth=8.27in, paperheight=11.69in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!10}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Replication I}\\
\midrule
a & bc & 1 & d\\
24.0 & 15.8 & 17.5 & 20.8 \\
ad & c & bd & b \\
27.5 & 24.3 & 22.5 & 18.3 \\
abc & cd & ab & ac \\
21.5 & 15.5 & 26.2 & 27.5 \\
abcd & acd & bcd & abd  \\
28.5 & 30.5 & 28.9 & 24.5 \\ 
\midrule
\end{tabular} & \rowcolors{1}{}{gray!10} \begin{tabular}{cccc}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Replication II}\\
\midrule
ab & abc & 1 & bd \\ 
12.1 & 14.5 & 10.5 & 13.5 \\ 
d & a & ac & bc \\ 
12.0 & 9.0 & 15.0 & 15.8 \\ 
c & abcd & cd & b \\ 
11.5 & 17.2 & 16.0 & 11.0 \\ 
bcd & ad & abd & acd \\ 
19.5 & 13.2 & 12.9 & 13.5 \\ 
\midrule
\end{tabular} \\
\rowcolors{1}{}{gray!10}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Replication III} \\
\midrule
a & 1 & bcd & abcd \\
26.0 & 18.5 & 29.8 & 25.8 \\
acd & ac & c & abc \\
35.0 & 25.7 & 30.5 & 25.4 \\
cd & ab & d & ad \\
17.8 & 26.0 & 24.5 & 30.2 \\
bc & bd & abd & b \\
17.9 & 20.4 & 25.4 & 15.8 \\
\end{tabular} & \rowcolors{1}{}{gray!10}
\begin{tabular}{cccc}
\multicolumn{4}{c}{Replication IV} \\
\midrule
abcd & a & 1 & abc \\ 
34.5 & 35.4 & 32.5 & 30.9 \\ 
acd & bc & bcd & d \\ 
45.3 & 43.5 & 30.4 & 28.9 \\ 
c & cd & ac & b \\ 
38.0 & 37.5 & 29.8 & 32.5 \\ 
abd & ab & bd & ad \\ 
36.5 & 30.5 & 30.0 & 38.5 \\
\end{tabular} \\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular} 
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I need rows colored alternatively but in doubles. That is, I need rows 2-3 in gray, rows 4-5 in white, rows 6-7 in gray and so on.

What should I do?

Comment: Hi ! Have a look on : https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! In general, when asking a question, you should show what work you've done so far. Are you familiar with the `tabular` environment?

Comment: If you can handle it, please read [this article](https://tug.org/TUGboat/tb38-3/tb120duck.pdf).

Comment: Thank u. I am new here. So didn't know. But I have edited my question. I hope this  works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A possible solution is to use `\hiderowcolors`/`\showrowcolors`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[ paperwidth=8.27in, paperheight=11.69in]{geometry}
\usepackage{booktabs, siunitx}
\usepackage[svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multirow}
\newcommand{\mytablecolor}{\rowcolors{2}{gray!10}{gray!10}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{cc}
            \toprule
            \mytablecolor
            \begin{tabular}{cccc}
                \multicolumn{4}{c}{Replication I}\\
                \midrule
                a & bc & 1 & d\\
                24.0 & 15.8 & 17.5 & 20.8 \\
                \hiderowcolors ad & c & bd & b \\
                27.5 & 24.3 & 22.5 & 18.3 \\
                \showrowcolors abc & cd & ab & ac \\
                21.5 & 15.5 & 26.2 & 27.5 \\
                \hiderowcolors abcd & acd & bcd & abd  \\
                28.5 & 30.5 & 28.9 & 24.5 \\ 
                \midrule
            \end{tabular} & 
            \mytablecolor
            \begin{tabular}{cccc}
                \multicolumn{4}{c}{Replication II}\\
                \midrule
                ab & abc & 1 & bd \\ 
                12.1 & 14.5 & 10.5 & 13.5 \\ 
                \hiderowcolors d & a & ac & bc \\ 
                12.0 & 9.0 & 15.0 & 15.8 \\ 
                \showrowcolors c & abcd & cd & b \\ 
                11.5 & 17.2 & 16.0 & 11.0 \\ 
                \hiderowcolors bcd & ad & abd & acd \\ 
                19.5 & 13.2 & 12.9 & 13.5 \\ 
                \midrule
            \end{tabular} \\
            \mytablecolor
            \begin{tabular}{cccc}
                \multicolumn{4}{c}{Replication III} \\
                \midrule
                a & 1 & bcd & abcd \\
                26.0 & 18.5 & 29.8 & 25.8 \\
                \hiderowcolors acd & ac & c & abc \\
                35.0 & 25.7 & 30.5 & 25.4 \\
                \showrowcolors cd & ab & d & ad \\
                17.8 & 26.0 & 24.5 & 30.2 \\
                \hiderowcolors bc & bd & abd & b \\
                17.9 & 20.4 & 25.4 & 15.8 \\
            \end{tabular} & 
            \mytablecolor
            \begin{tabular}{cccc}
                \multicolumn{4}{c}{Replication IV} \\
                \midrule
                abcd & a & 1 & abc \\ 
                34.5 & 35.4 & 32.5 & 30.9 \\ 
                \hiderowcolors acd & bc & bcd & d \\ 
                45.3 & 43.5 & 30.4 & 28.9 \\ 
                \showrowcolors c & cd & ac & b \\ 
                38.0 & 37.5 & 29.8 & 32.5 \\ 
                \hiderowcolors abd & ab & bd & ad \\ 
                36.5 & 30.5 & 30.0 & 38.5 \\
            \end{tabular} \\
            \bottomrule 
        \end{tabular} 
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Grazie CarLaTex :-)